Convergence of sequence of functions of a random variable
Let $g_n$ be a sequence of functions and $X$ a random variable. The assumptions on $g_n$ and $X$ are precisely part of the question.
Assume that $g_n$ converges to $g$ (the mode of convergence is part of the question).
Then, does the sequence of random variables $Y_n=g_n(X)$ converge to $Y=g(X)$? In what sense?
My intuition tells me that if $g_n$ converges pointwise to $g$ then $Y_n$ should converge almost surely. However, I cannot be sure that for a fixed $\omega$, the sequence $g_n(X(\omega))$ converges to $g(X(\omega))$ since such $\omega$ can be so that $X(\omega)$ belongs to the null set where $g_n$ does not converge to. But is the probability of such $\omega$'s zero?
Summary:

Is almost everywhere convergence enough to guarante almost sure convergence?
Does $L^1$ convergence of $g_n$ to $g$ also guarantee almost sure convergence?
Do we need absolute continuity of $X$ in one or both cases?

Thanks a lot!
Attempt:

let $N=\{x: \lim_n g_n(x)\neq g(x)\}$ then $\lambda(N)=0$ where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure. This is by assumption. Then, we would like to look at $A=\{\omega: X(\omega)\in N\}$. Since $X$ is a random variable and $N$ is a Borel set (is it?) then $A$ is measurable.

$$\mathbb{P}[A]=\mathbb{P}[\omega: X(\omega)\in N]=F_X(N)$$
and if $F$ is absolutely continuous then yes, I get $0$.

Here, I do not know how to reach almost sure convergence, only in probability by Chebyshev's inequality:
$$\mathbb{P}[|g_n(X)-g(X)|>\varepsilon]\leq \frac{1}{\varepsilon} \mathbb{E}[|g_n(X)-g(X)|]=\frac{1}{\varepsilon} \int_{\mathbb{R}}|g_n(X)-g(X)|dF(x)$$
but then I'm not sure whether I need to assume that $dF(x)=f(x)dx$ or if I need to assume that $f$ is bounded or something.


Suppose $g_{n}$'s are functions from $\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$. Now let $g_{n}(x)\to g(x)$ for all irrational $x$ and it does not converge to $g$ for any rational $x$. For example, you can take $g_{n}$'s to be $g$ itself where $g=\mathbf{1}{\Bbb{R}\setminus\Bbb{Q}}$. Take $X$ such that $P(X=\pi)=\frac{1}{2}$ and $P(X=0)=\frac{1}{2}$. So for a set of probability $\frac{1}{2}$, we have for all such $\omega$, $g{n}(X(\omega))$ will not converge. In fact you will not even have convergence in probability and hence not in $L^{1}$ too.

Interesting! So, actually, one needs absolute continuity? Then it is true that one gets almost sure convergence, right?

Yes. And $A={X^{-1}(N)}$ is a Borel set by definition of a random variable. i.e. a Random variable is a measurable function. So $X^{-1}(B)$ must be measurable if $B$ is a Borel set. However, for $L^{1}$ convergence, you'll need to assume other things. Like if $g_{n}$ restricted to the support of the distribution of $X$, is uniformly bounded in $n$ almost everywhere, then by the DCT, you can conclude that $|\int (g_{n}(x)f(x)-g(x)f(x)),dx|\to 0$ and hence you'll have $L^{1}$ convergence. There could be other assumptions as well which are not as strong as boundedness.

Also note that once you have that the distribution of $X$ is absolutely continuous, you automatically find the density function $f$ by the Radon Nikodym theorem and hence $dF(x)=f(x),dx$

Yes, that is what I meant by abs. cont. (so that $f$ is a version of the density). Then, I see that it was not direct, and abs. cont. seems to be sufficient. Very nicely explained, thank you! If you write it as an answer I can mark it as an answer to close the question, only if you want, or course!

Suppose you take $g_{n}=g=\mathbf{1}_{\Bbb{R}\setminus\Bbb{Q}}$ and take $X$ to be such that $P(X=\pi)=\frac{1}{2}$ and $P(X=0)=\frac{1}{2}$. Then it is clear that $g_{n}(X)$ cannot converge to $g(X)$ for a set of probability $\frac{1}{2}$. This rules out convergence in probability, almost sure convergence and $L^{1}$ convergence.
If the distribution of $X$ is absolutely continuous wrt Lebesgue measure, then $P(X^{-1}(N))=F_{X}(N)=0$ as $\lambda(N)=0$ going by the notation in your question and you'll have pointwise for all $\omega\in \{X^{-1}(N)\}^{c}$ which is a set of probability $1$ and hence you have almost sure convergence (and hence also convergence in probability).
If you assume that there exists some $M$ such that $|g_{n}(x)|\leq M$ for all $n$ almost everywhere. Then you can conclude using DCT that $E(|g_{n}(X)-g(X)|)=\int_{\Bbb{R}}|g_{n}(x)-g(x)|f(x)\,dx\to 0$ using DCT as $|g_{n}(x)-g(x)|f(x)\leq 2Mf(x)$ and the RHS is Lebesgue integrable. This will give you $L^{1}$ convergence.
You don't really need such a strong assumption like boundedness but rather something like $|\sup_{n}g_{n}(x)f(x)|$ being integrable is enough. But strictly speaking, you cannot tackle these in full generality and often such convergences will depend on the context.
